# Can not pull updated data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My ASP.NET MVC & EF project has a base controller as follows:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private Context _database;

    public Context Db
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_database == null)
            { 
                _database = new Context(); 
            }

            return _database;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_database != null)
        { 
            _database.Dispose(); 
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

My ajax save setting code is:

```
public JsonResult SiteGenelAyarlari(List<GeneralSettings> gs)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       gs.ForEach(item => Db.GeneralSettings.AddOrUpdate(s => s.LanguageId, item));
       Db.SaveChanges();
   }

   return Json("Saved fine.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But when I update a value in the database, after a page refresh the new values do not get pulled. What am I missing?

If I re-run project, new values are being returned fine.

Comment: seems you pull presaved values from the context instead of the database. try disposing and re-initializing the context. Maybe there is a way to force EF to create a query for entries in its DbSets, I don't know of any though.

Comment: Even I update value in DB manually and refresh page, it does not pull mew value. I already tried disposing it.